# Different Queue ID For Same Queue With Same Project Collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

We have a pool and its ID is 1, added agent to it, gives the queue id as 3. We have two different projects in same collection. While creating the build definition for both of them when try to fill agent queue we get the same queue selected however, looking at corresponding build definition Json we see a different queue Id's for the same queue. Is that a bug ???

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug.

An agent pool is an independent entity scoped at the server/account level.

An agent queue is a "pointer" to an agent pool, to limit access to agent pools to only projects that require them. Each agent queue has a different ID, because they are different entities, regardless of what agent pool they point to.